# How to change straight quotes to curly quotes in MS Office PowerPoint with autocorrect turned off

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-powerpoint-2007, microsoft-powerpoint

I do not want to use MS Office autocorrect option that is changing automatically straigh quotes to curly quotes ("smart quotes").

Most of the time I prefere straight quotes, but sometimes, in a selected place, I would like to change a straight quote to a smart quote. How can I do that?

I am using MS Office 2007 PowerPoint.

Answer (score 4):

If you know exactly when you want an individual curly quote, why not type it in directly?

**Alt+NumPad 0147** will give you a left double quotation mark, i.e while holding down the Alt key, press 0-1-4-7 on the Numeric Pad.

**Alt+NumPad 0148** will give you a right double quoation mark

*If you open charmap and search for 'quotation mark' you can find the numpad codes for other types of quotation marks also.* Note that the leading zero is important to make it work, otherwise you might see `ôö` instead of `“”`.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be a find-and-replace, using Regular Expressions to check whether there is a character after the " or not to determine which direction to point the quotes.

For what it is worth, "smart quotes" are not generally supported in, for example, copy-paste operations on the Web due to lack of support for those characters - you are likely to run into errors if you try.